# node.js wait for file operation to complete

Tags: node.js, web-services, asynchronous

I am brand new at node.js and I need to write a web server that takes data and write it to a file.  that file is then used in an external program.

my problem is that node.js executes the external program before the data is completely written to the file.  How can I wait for it to complete before executing the external program

```
var http = require('http')
var map = require('through2-map')
var fs = require('fs')
var str = ""
var sh = require('execSync');
var tmp_filename = ""

    function random (low, high) {
    return Math.random() * (high - low) + low;
}

function execute_program(){
  var command = 'ruby ' + __dirname +  '/check_content.rb --file '+ tmp_filename
  var result = sh.exec(command);
  console.log('return code ' + result.code);
  console.log('stdout + stderr ' + result.stdout);
  return result.stdout
}

function write_to_file (chunk){
  str = chunk.toString();
  fs.appendFile(tmp_filename, str, function (err){
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');    
    }
  ) 
}

var server = http.createServer( function(req, res){
    tmp_filename = '/tmp/tmp_template_' + random(1000, 99999) + '.template'
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    message = req.pipe(map(function (chunk, res) {
      write_to_file(chunk);
    }))
    var out = execute_program();
    res.write(out)
    message.pipe(res)
  }
)

server.listen(8000)
```

Comment: I think your whole question reduces to: How can I be notified of the completion of `req.pipe`? Is that right?

Comment: correct, i need to extract all the data sent and write it to the file in that section of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mike S.  The message.pipe(res) and res.write(out) is redundant...but i did some research and used async.waterfall package and the following worked for me.  but will take your suggestion for optimization

```
var http = require('http');
var map = require('through2-map');
var fs = require('fs');
var str = "";
var sh = require('execSync');
var async = require('async');
var tmp_filename = "";

function random (low, high) {
     return Math.random() * (high - low) + low;
}

function write_to_file (chunk){
  str = chunk.toString();
  fs.appendFile(tmp_filename, str, function (err){
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');    
    }
  ) 
}

function execute_program(){
  var command = 'ruby ' + __dirname +  '/check_content --file ' +  tmp_filename
  var result = sh.exec(command);
  console.log('return code ' + result.code);
  console.log('stdout + stderr ' + result.stdout);
  return result.stdout
}

async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
      var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
          callback(null, req, res)
        }
      ).listen(8000);      
    },
    function(req, res, callback){
      tmp_filename = '/tmp/tmp_template_' + random(1000, 99999) + '.template'
      var message = req.pipe(map(function (chunk) {
        write_to_file(chunk);
      }))
      setTimeout(function () {
        callback(null, req, res, message);
      }, 666);
    },
    function(req, res, message, callback){
      var out = execute_program()
      res.write(out)
      message.pipe(res)
      callback(null, 'done');
    }
  ])
```

Answer (score 0):

***Note:** I'm not sure what you're attempting with `res.write(out)` and then `message.pipe(res)`. That will write the output from your ruby script to the response and then it looks like you're piping the request body in after that. As it is, the `message.pipe(res)` line won't work because you'll be trying to pipe from a writable stream, which you can't do. **For the purpose of this answer I'm going to assume you don't want the `message.pipe(res)` line; please correct me if I'm wrong.***

### Simple / Quick Answer

The simplest answer is to listen for the `end` event on `req` and then execute your program, etc. when that event fires:

```
var server = http.createServer( function(req, res){
    tmp_filename = '/tmp/tmp_template_' + random(1000, 99999) + '.template'
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    req.on('end', function() {
        var out = execute_program();
        res.write(out);
        res.end();
    });
    req.pipe(map(function (chunk, res) {
        write_to_file(chunk);
    }));
  }
)
```

### Optimization: [`fs.createWriteStream()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options)

You could also use `fs.createWriteStream()` instead of appending chunks with `fs.appendFile()`. That would look like:

```
var server = http.createServer( function(req, res){
    tmp_filename = '/tmp/tmp_template_' + random(1000, 99999) + '.template'
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    req.on('end', function() {
        var out = execute_program();
        res.write(out);
        res.end();
    });
    req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tmp_filename));
  }
)
```

With that in place, you can remove your entire `write_to_file` function.

That will also prevent a problem you might have if you happen to get the same random number for your temp file; with your current code, you'll append to the existing file, which is probably not what you want. If for some reason you *do* want to append to the file in that case, you can just pass the `a` flag (for append) to `fs.createWriteStream`: `fs.createWriteStream(tmp_filename, {flags: 'a'});`.